# UIImageView resize in orientation change to landscape mode programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have a problem where I need to rotate an UIImageView and resize depending if it's Portraite mode or Landscape mode.

I've managed to get the image view to rotate correctly, by doing as the answer in this related problem says: [Rotate UIImageView Depending on iPhone Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377754/rotate-uiimageview-depending-on-iphone-orientation).

This is my code for the rotation (for now I've only focused on rotating it to left landscape):

```
- (void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
          curve:(int)curve degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    float angle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees);    
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(
                        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                                         160.0f-self.view.center.x,
                                                         240.0f-self.view.center.y
                                                         ),angle);
    image.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

How I initiate the UIImageView:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
self.testImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
self.testImageView.image = image;
self.testImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.testImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

What's happening now is that the Image gets rotated but has the same size as in portrait mode in landscape mode, but is centered (that I understand why, as I did the rotation as the answer to the linked question).

So, what I want is that the image is viewed in fullscreen, as the original image has the scale to fit in fullscreen landscape. As I've set

```
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

my original naive thought that this would magically rescale to fit the proper landscape scale. That's obviously not the case. Any hints?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by "the original image has the scale to fit in fullscreen landscape", but if you want the image to retain its aspect ratio while filling the image view (at the expense of some clipping), you could try `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Comment: Yes I tried the AspectFill but as you mention the image gets to big and is shown outside the screen. In that case I want it correctly scaled but in the expense it doesnt fill the whole screen (since the original image scale might not fit the iphone landscape screen), but the problem now is that it's way to small in landscape (not resized at all).

Answer (score -1):

Try using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and set in your parent view property autoresizesSubviews to YES. Image should resize automagically.

Comment: Unfortunately that bring no change.